# Two storyboards .. Same event .. Same property

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, expression-blend, eventtrigger

**How** to change respectively between two storyboards within the same ex. MouseDown event or button Click event targeting same property ex. visibility.

1st click -> Visibility from 1 to 0 ( Fade Out )
2nd click -> Visibility from 0 to 1 ( Fade In )
3rd click -> Visibility from 1 to 0 ( Fade Out )
4th click -> Visibility from 0 to 1 ( Fade In )
and so on ...

**Fade In**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="FadeIn">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard >
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>             
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers> 
    </Style>
```

**Fade Out**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="FadeOut">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard >
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>             
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers> 
    </Style>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't see an easy way with no code behind.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Do you want to click a button once and have another object fade out, then click the button again and have the same object then object fade in? Sorry but your description of the effect you're after seems a little difficult to visualize.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, this's what I meant. Sorry for my English as it isn't my native language

Comment: @NestorArturo I wan't to trigger storyboards without code behind.

Comment: Have you tried VisualStateManager with GoToStateAction, or just basic ControlStoryBoardAction?

Comment: Well... really don't see an easy way with no code behind. Code behind is not forbidden at all :o) Maybe changing the template for a CheckBox (or any other two-state control) you could achieve that.

Comment: @NestorArturo Yes, It's very trivial by code behind. But one day on SO I saw an XAML technique which was very brilliant, Now I searched for it alot till I started this question.

Comment: Why not use a toggle button instead of a normal button? You could do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think a toggle button is the appropriate control for this, but if you need to use a normal button for whatever reason, use two of them instead of one:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="TestBed.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Hide_Border">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Btn_Show">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Btn_Hide">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Show_Border">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Btn_Show">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Btn_Hide">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="Btn_Hide">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Hide_Border}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="Btn_Show">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Show_Border_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource Show_Border}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="Btn_Hide" Content="Hide" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="Btn_Show" Content="Show" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Border x:Name="border" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" />     
</Grid>
```